# How to get a direct download link without visiting uploader page

Tags: html, download, hosting

I have hosted my files on a 3rd party site. but when I click the link given it takes me to their website and I have to click download again there to download the software. Is there a way that I can upload to a storage and download on a single click itself?

I mean is there any other free file hosting servers that give direct download links?

Answer (score 1):

Use Dropbox.
Upload the file, share  the file, copy its link, then change the end of the link where it says =0 and change it to =1